# How to install ADB driver for any android device?

Tags: android, adb, winusb

I am an android developer. I have a new HTC Inspire 4g phone but I don't know how to install usb driver for it.
This is my android_winusb.inf file:

```
;
; Android WinUsb driver installation.
;
[Version]
Signature           = "$Windows NT$"
Class               = AndroidUsbDeviceClass
ClassGuid           = {3F966BD9-FA04-4ec5-991C-D326973B5128}
Provider            = %ProviderName%
DriverVer           = 12/06/2010,4.0.0000.00000
CatalogFile.NTx86   = androidwinusb86.cat
CatalogFile.NTamd64 = androidwinusba64.cat

;
; This section seems to be required for WinUsb driver installation.
; If this section is removed the installer will report an error
; "Required section not found in INF file".
;
[ClassInstall32]
Addreg = AndroidWinUsbClassReg

[AndroidWinUsbClassReg]
HKR,,,0,%ClassName%
HKR,,Icon,,-1

[Manufacturer]
%ProviderName% = Google, NTx86, NTamd64

[Google.NTx86]
; HTC Dream
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C02&MI_01
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0FFF
; HTC Magic
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C03&MI_01
;
;Moto Sholes
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_22B8&PID_41DB
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_22B8&PID_41DB&MI_01
;
;Google NexusOne
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E12&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E22&MI_01

[Google.NTamd64]
; HTC Dream
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C02&MI_01
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0FFF
; HTC Magic
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C03&MI_01
;
;Moto Sholes
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_22B8&PID_41DB
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_22B8&PID_41DB&MI_01
;
;Google NexusOne
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02&MI_01
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E11
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E12&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4E22&MI_01

[USB_Install]
Include = winusb.inf
Needs   = WINUSB.NT

[USB_Install.Services]
Include     = winusb.inf
AddService  = WinUSB,0x00000002,WinUSB_ServiceInstall

[WinUSB_ServiceInstall]
DisplayName     = %WinUSB_SvcDesc%
ServiceType     = 1
StartType       = 3
ErrorControl    = 1
ServiceBinary   = %12%\WinUSB.sys

[USB_Install.Wdf]
KmdfService = WINUSB, WinUSB_Install

[WinUSB_Install]
KmdfLibraryVersion  = 1.9

[USB_Install.HW]
AddReg  = Dev_AddReg

[Dev_AddReg]
HKR,,DeviceInterfaceGUIDs,0x10000,"{F72FE0D4-CBCB-407d-8814-9ED673D0DD6B}"

[USB_Install.CoInstallers]
AddReg    = CoInstallers_AddReg
CopyFiles = CoInstallers_CopyFiles

[CoInstallers_AddReg]
HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000,"WdfCoInstaller01009.dll,WdfCoInstaller","WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll"

[CoInstallers_CopyFiles]
WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll

[DestinationDirs]
CoInstallers_CopyFiles=11

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DISK_NAME%,,,\i386
2 = %DISK_NAME%,,,\amd64

[SourceDisksFiles.x86]
WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll  = 1
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll = 1

[SourceDisksFiles.amd64]
WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll  = 2
WdfCoInstaller01009.dll = 2

[Strings]
ProviderName                = "Google, Inc."
SingleAdbInterface          = "Android ADB Interface"
CompositeAdbInterface       = "Android Composite ADB Interface"
SingleBootLoaderInterface   = "Android Bootloader Interface"
WinUSB_SvcDesc              = "Android USB Driver"
DISK_NAME                   = "Android WinUsb installation disk"
ClassName                   = "Android Phone"
```

Comment: What OS are you working in? And what's the concrete problem: you can't find a driver, or you can't install it?

Comment: I'm working on Windows 7 64bit. I have downloaded USB-Driver package provided by Google but I can't install HTC Inspire 4g usb driver (like what I did with Nexus one).

Comment: [use the oem drivers or pdanet](http://www.androidsim.net/2009/08/how-to-1-how-to-install-usb-driver-on.html) said by [@TonyLe](http://stackoverflow.com/users/775564/tony-le) [*answer deleted*]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have found a solution by myself.
I use the PDANet tool to find the driver automatically.

http://www.junefabrics.com/android/download.php

Comment: why @Nguyen Minh Binh it doesn't automatically detect your device when connected?

Comment: Yeah, Sure! But I just connect my device as USB storage only. I cant deploy my application on it.

Comment: you're the best, I was trying to find my android driver for a month :)

Comment: You are great Nguyen Minh Binh... It helped me... Thanks :)

Comment: Working perfect with Allview phones! Thx!

Answer (score 6):

**[UNIVERSAL ADB DRIVER](http://adbdriver.com/)**

I have thesame issue before but i solved it easily by just following this steps:

*connect your android phone in a debugging mode
(to enable debugging mode goto settings scroll down About Phone scroll down tap seven times Build Number and it will automatically enable developer option turn on developer options and check USB debugging)

download [Universal ADB Driver Installer](http://adbdriver.com/)

*choose Adb Driver Installer (Universal)

*install it 
*it will automatically detect your android device(any kind of brand)
*chose the device and install

Comment: Your answer was the ONLY answer that worked for my Lenovo TAB10. If only someone had pointed me at your answer a week ago!

Answer (score 2):

If no other driver package worked for your obscure device go read how to make a [truly universal abd and fastboot driver](http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-make-truly-universal-adb-and.html) out of Google's USB driver. The trick is to use `CompatibleID` instead of `HardwareID`
in the driver's [INF Models section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547456(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to install or use any third party tools.

The drivers located in `...\Android\Sdk\extras\google\usb_driver` work just fine.

**Step 1:** In `Device Manager`, Right click on the malfunctioning `Android ADB Interface` driver

**Step 2:** Select `Update Driver Software`

**Step 3:** Select `Browse my computer for driver software`

**Step 4**: Select `Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer`

**Step 5:** Select `Have Disk`

This window pops up:

[image]

**Step 6:** Copy the location of the Google USB Driver `(...\Android\Sdk\extras\google\usb_driver)` or browse to it.

**Step 7:** Click `Ok`

This window pops up:

[image]

**Step 8:** Select `Android ADB Interface` and click `Next`

The window below pops up with a warning:

[image]

That's it. You driver installation will start and in a few seconds, you should be able to see your device