# Android ADB doesn't see device

Tags: android, adb, tablet

I'm trying to run my applications on OMEGA T107 tablet. But `adb` doesn't see my device. I tried almost everything.

Comment: What is almost everything???

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159532/how-to-install-adb-driver-for-any-android-device/62916180#62916180

Comment: FOR LINUX CHECK HERE: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144966/how-do-i-get-my-device-detected-by-adb-on-linux

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I tried all the ways listed on the web for a whole day, but I didn't get any solutions. Then, I followed a link and in just two minutes my problem was solved!

By the way, it's for Windows users!

Find out the vendor id of the device from device manager.
To do this, connect the OTG port to the USB port of your computer.
Go to Start Menu and right-click on “My Computer” and chose “Properties”.
Select the “Devices” option which will open “Device Manager”.
Select your device (mostly in USB devices or Other devices) and right-click and choose “Properties”.
Choose the “Details” tab and select “Hardware Ids” from the property dropdown, you can see the hardware id, in my case it was x2207 .
Open android_winusb.inf and add these lines:

```
;<Device name>   in our case I gave MK808
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_INSTALL, USB\VID_2207&PID_0010&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_INSTALL, USB\VID_2207&PID_0010&REV_0222&MI_01
```

Open  C:\Users\.android\adb_usb.ini and add the following entry

```
0x<device id>  .. in our case it is 0x2207
```

Restart ADB by

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Now ADB should recognize the device.

Comment: Thanks, got my MIO A105 up and running now! On OSX the vendor ID can be found in "System Information > Hardware > USB". The adb_usb.ini file can be found in ~/.android

Comment: /!\ The link redirects me to a phishy news site that tries to load unauthenticated scripts and install chrome extensions, a link update would be appreciated

Comment: I already describe everything which was in the link. so there is no need to visit the link. @NinoFiliu
I will remove the link to prevent any harmful script. Thanks for mentioning

Comment: Why doesn't this mention where android_winusb.inf is? I found like 6 of them on my PC.

Comment: @ScottF you can download any mobile driver, but the best choice is to download google one from the SDK MANAGER and change and use that file there. Its in Extra Folder

Comment: cant get adb_usb.ini

Comment: FOR LINUX CHECK HERE: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144966/how-do-i-get-my-device-detected-by-adb-on-linux

Answer (score 26):

Some of these answers are pretty old, so maybe it's changed in recent times, but I had similar issues and I solved it by:

1. Loading the USB drivers for the device - Samsung S6
2. Enable Developer tools on the phone.
3. On the device, go to Settings - Applications - Development - Check USB Debugging
4. Reboot O/S (Windows 7 - 64bit)
5. Open Visual Studio

I think it was step 3 that had me stumped for a while.  I'd enabled developer tools, but I didn't specifically enable the "USB Debugging" but.

Comment: The 3rd step worked for me in the latest version(in 2020). Thanks.

Comment: Develop Options - USB debugging ON did the trick for me as well  Using a n "hena T107" tablet- Thanks

Comment: FOR LINUX CHECK HERE: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144966/how-do-i-get-my-device-detected-by-adb-on-linux

Answer (score 19):

I had same issue, none of the solutions worked for me.

Open Settings Menu ->  Developer Options -> USB Debugging should be on

### Android 11

Settings -> System -> Developer options -> USB debugging

Comment: Using android 11 I had to go to Settings -> System -> Developer options -> USB debugging. (Slightly the same but since I had to search a bit, I add this comment ^^)

Comment: Wow, I use my Android 12 phone regularly for development and somehow it turned that option off by itself. Not sure why. I didn't event think that this would be off.

Answer (score 15):

The normal way to fix this is indeed to restart the adb server :

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

then

```
adb devices -l
```

should list connected devices

But it possible that it doesnt fix the problem. It appends to me.

I had to `disable/enable` the debug mode on the device, and then restart adb server.

Comment: that does not solve the problem, I've been doing that for hours. It's something more

Comment: Yup. I was really puzzled because the PHONE said "usb debugging connected" AND "lsusb" clearly showed it, AND the same model of phone worked fine with the same computer yesterday.

Answer (score 8):

On Windows it is most probably that the device drivers are not installed properly.

First, install `Google USB Driver` from Android SDK Manager.

Then, go to `Start`, right-click on `My Computer`, select `Properties` and go to `Device Manager` on the left. Locate you device under `Other Devices` (`Unknown devices`, `USB Devices`). Right-click on it and select `Properties`. Navigate to `Driver` tab. Select `Update Driver` and then `Browse my computer for driver software`. Choose `%ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\extras\google\usb_driver` directory. Windows should find and install drivers there. Then run `adb kill-server`. Next time you do `adb devices` the device should be in the list.

Answer (score 8):

**Not all USB cables can transfer data**. Try using a different USB cable if your device is charging, but doesn't establish a connection to your machine.

Read more: [How to tell a USB charge-only cable from a USB data cable - Dignited](https://www.dignited.com/50330/usb-data-cable-vs-usb-charging-cable/)

Comment: Finally this worked!

Comment: Switching cables worked, thanks! The cable I was using worked for an old phone but not the new device, which was picky and wanted a new cable.

Answer (score 5):

What operating system are you on? If you running Windows you will want to make sure you have the drivers. You should also make sure that your Android SDK Manager is not only installed, but it also contains some additional things for different devices. Not sure if yours is in there or not.

Make sure that your phone has debugging enabled. I found myself having to run

> adb kill-server
>
> adb devices

often.

Comment: what host platform are you on?

Comment: Did you download the drivers? That was my first suggestion.

Comment: yes this one from google, using SDK manager. I thought that drivers could not mach but cant find anything for this tablet :/

Comment: Yeah. I couldn't easily find a driver for that tablet either. Tough look. Let us know if you find one. Should have factored that into your purchasing decision. You can always install Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 4):

On windows, you will need to install drivers for the device for adb to recognize it. To see if the drivers are installed, check the device manager. If there is any "unrecognized device" in the device manager, the drivers are not installed. You can usually get the adb drivers from the manufacturers.

Comment: i know, ofcourse i`ve checked, drivers are installed i think just drivers from goodle aren`t good one

Comment: Google doesnt provide drivers for devices from different manufacturers. When you say drivers are installed, did you install it yourself, perhaps from a CD that came with the tablet?

Comment: Try installing [PdaNet](http://junefabrics.com/android/) for windows. When installing this application, they also install many drivers for different devices. I've found this to be a single easy source for installing many  device drivers.

Comment: no i dodn`t becouse i haven`t any cd and can`t find drivers that will be mach :/

Answer (score 3):

For Windows 8 64 bit with a Nexus 10 device, this worked for me:

https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver

It has a link at the bottom to this:

http://download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup.msi

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me in my Astro Tab A737 
Download and install PdaNet+ from http://pdanet.co/a/ in your computer.

follow all steps in the wizard while installing .Once the drivers are installed Android studio should recognize the tablet.

Also, make sure the device is in PTP mode.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling all old "Android ADB Interface" drivers that were installed previously and then installing the new one worked for me.

Comment: Tried everything, updated to the latest google driver, edited android_winusb.inf 
 and adb_usb.ini -- nothing worked until I uninstalled ADB driver and let windows (7) install a new one automatically.

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable `Developer options`.
2. Set `USB debugging` on.
3. It can show a dialog `Allow USB debugging?` (with RSA fingerprint). Confirm it.
4. If the device hasn't appeared in a device list, try to eject USB wire from the smarthpone and plug again.
5. Try to change a connection option between:

- Power charging
- File transfer
- Media transfer
- USB-modem
- MIDI.

Probably it will install a USB-driver. Also it can help when the driver has already been isntalled.

6. Make sure you have a good data-cable. Sometimes data-cables get damaged, especially cheap.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging needs to be [enabled](https://wiki.lineageos.org/adb_fastboot_guide.html) on the target device in order for `adb` to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind while you connecting device Android propose to select one of possible connection options.
In my case:

1. File transfer
2. Power charging
3. Media

Not all types of connection will work with ADB. In my case need to select Power charging to be able to connect to ADB

Answer (score 0):

Intel has a peach of an article on this. It's all the same driver.  It's just a Device ID mismatch in the Inf file which can be edited, or Windows forced to Install the driver we point it to. Intel's article is very thorough and takes care of every hurdle you come across. The link - https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/installing-android-debug-bridge-adb-usb-driver-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Device Manager

[image: Screenshot Device Manager]

2. Right-click Android Composite ADB Interface
3. Uninstall devices
4. Right-click your LocalPC then select Scan for hardware changes

Your device should be enabled

- Open Command Prompt
- `adb kill-server`
- `adb start-server`
- `adb devices`

[image: Screenshot Console]