# adb doesn't see android device ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, adb

Ubuntu 14.04
My device is lg l90 d405

lsusb output:

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1004:633e LG Electronics, Inc.
```

Developer options is checked.
I edited rule file:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", ATTR{idProduct}=="633e", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/the-most-comprehensive-write-up-on-how.html

Answer (score 1):

Change USB options to "Send images(PTP)" in "USB PC connection".

Comment: Alternatively, remaining in MTP mode, you can change the USB configuration.  LG's MTP mode on my 1004:633e phone has two configuration modes as seen in lsusb -v, but linux selects the wrong one.  There's probably a way to make linux prefer the second configuration when in MTP mode (custom usb driver maybe?), but you can change to it temporarily using pyusb's set_configuration.  This allowed me to regain adb/scrcpy access to a phone with a non-functional screen.

Answer (score 1):

kill adb server and restart it again and ubuntu should show your device.If it doesnt work, try commands with `sudo` permission

ADB Commands:

```
1.adb kill-server
2.adb start-server
3.adb devices
```

for more information, [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810537/android-adb-doesnt-see-device)