# Android device driver for Astro Tab A724

Tags: android

I have searched all over and tried many things to get adb to recognize that my Astro Tab A724 is a connected device. Some of the things I have tried are:[Google Android USB Driver and ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709263/google-android-usb-driver-and-adb) and [Android ADB doesn't see device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810537/android-adb-doesnt-see-device) . In the device manager, when I right click on my device and choose "Update Drive Software...", Windows 10 is unable to find the software for my tablet. Anyone, please help me. :)

Also, adb works for another device I have, but I now need to test my app on the Astro Tab. I have also gone to http://astroqueo.com/ in search of a support page that will tell me about drivers I need, but I am unable to find anything on their site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it appears your real goal is to get your A724 working with ADB, I can tell you it does work. I own both the Astro Tab A724 and A924. I use the A724 with Android Studio for testing Android apps and ADB works fine for me.

When I first purchased these devices off Amazon, I was sent some additional instruction from the manufacturer via Amazon. A link was provided with detailed instructions. To get your A724  working on ADB for Android Studio (in Windows 10):

Step 1: Follow manufacturers instructions to update firmware here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvwxt2kk7kl72i9/A724%20-%20Instructions%20on%20Updating%20Firmware.docx?dl=0 .

Step 2: Setup your device to enable developer options (go to "Settings->About Tablet", tap "Build number" five times, then go to "Settings->Developer options", and configure per your needs).

When everything is configured correctly:
In Android Studio (currently 2.1.1 for me) when you go to run your app, the device will show up in the "Select Deployment Target" window under the "Connected Devices" section as "Actions AstroTab_A724 (Android 5.0.2, API 21)".

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Astro Tab does not have any USB drivers in existence.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for my Astro Tab A737 
Download and install PdaNet+ from http://pdanet.co/a/ in your syatem.  Run and and install it. follow all the steps in the wizard . Once the drivers are installed Android studio should recognize the tablet. 
Also, make sure the device is in PTP mode.