# Cannot Install Android USB Drivers (Windows 7)

Tags: android, windows, adb, drivers

I have a Lenovo TAB10, which I'm trying to connect to my Toshiba laptop for Android USB debugging. Obviously, I need drivers for this before moving on to installing the ADB proper.

Problem is, I can't install drivers. Every time I try to install ADB drivers via Device Manager, I get an error dialogue saying "Windows could not find driver files for your device". This is despite the fact that the files I've downloaded contain everything normally found in driver file packages - CAB files, DLLs, a relevant .INF file, etc. For some bizarre reason, Windows 7 refuses to recognise their existence.

Also, installing Universal ADB does NOT work. Windows 7 refuses to recognise that these drivers are valid ADB drivers.

The weird part is, I can perform file transfers between the laptop and the tablet, and the tablet is recognised for this purpose. Unfortunately, the Lenovo_Suite package that handles this, doesn't appear to contain ADB drivers, and nothing resembling recognisable ADB drivers appears in Device Manager even when Lenovo_Suite is running.

This has been causing me much frustration for a week now. Does anyone have a solution?

EDIT: UPDATED WITH MORE DETAILS ...

Here's a more detailed exposition of the sequence of events.

[1] Boot tablet.

[2] Connect tablet to laptop, with developer options and USB debugging enabled.

[3] Windows Dialogue appears, saying "Do you wish Lenovo_Suite To Make Changes To Your Computer?"

[4] Click "Yes" and run it.

[5] In Windows Explorer, Lenovo TAB10 appears as a device under "Computer" in the left pane. Device is accessible, and I can transfer files to and from the tablet.

[6] Run Device Manager.

[7] In Device Manager, under "Portable Devices", Lenovo TAB10 is visible, with no accompanying error indications.

[8] Under "Other Devices", ADB Interface is visible, but with a yellow exclamation mark.

[9] Right click on "ADB Interface", select "Update Driver Software".

[10] When the dialogue appears, select ""Browse my computer for driver software" and do this manually.

[11] Navigate to the folder containing the downloaded driver software for the ADB interface.

[12] Click "Next".

[13] Dialogue appears. "Windows could not find driver software for your device".

Now, my reasoning is, that there HAS to exist something resembling basic USB drivers for the tablet resident on the laptop, otherwise, Windows Explorer would not be able to recognise the tablet and perform file transfers. If there were NO device drivers for the tablet resident at all on my laptop, Windows Explorer would surely be unable to recognise the tablet? On that basis, I conclude that SOME drivers exist for my tablet and are resident on the laptop.

However, when I enable developer options, and try installing drivers for the ADB interface, the above sequence [1] to [13] happens every time. Doesn't matter what drivers I try to install manually, the same thing happens.

Furthermore, when I try a different approach, using the Universal ADB Driver, and its custom installer, Device Manager refuses to recognise that drivers for the ADB Interface have been installed. Nothing works.

Comment: "Windows could not find driver files **for your device**".

Comment: But strangely, there ARE drivers in existence for file transfers etc. Otherwise I wouldn't have been able to perform this function.

Comment: There's nothing strange about drivers being available for your device and the driver you are trying to install not being compatible with your device. I do not understand the question you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

does windows shows any error while installing driver for your tab.

Sometimes You may need to boot Windows with **Driver Signing Enforcement** *disabled* to get the drivers installed.

[ADB interface driver from lenovo support](https://support.lenovo.com/in/en/downloads/ds022366)

Comment: UPDATE: Cristiana214's answer from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159532/how-to-install-adb-driver-for-any-android-device

was the one that worked, and it works BEAUTIFULLY. Give her a chocolate gateau!